# Rails 4: has_many through associated object never return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two Model, Post and Category. They are connected by has_many through association. Categorization is the through table.

```
@post= Post.find(params[:Post_id])
@category = @post.categories
```

Some of my post are not under any category. It is possible to post without selecting any category. Problem is @category never show nil. I perform this check

```
<% if @category %>

    <% else %>

    <% end %>
```

This code never goes in else block even though there are no categories. Why is that? How can I check nil in this case?

Comment: Is the discrepancy due to you translating?  i.e. you don't have `@vertifungsrichtungs` in your controller code

Comment: It will give you empty active records array not nil ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@post.categories` returns an activerecord relation,not nil.  Because you're using rails I'd check it's presence using [present?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)

```
<% if @vertiefungsrichtungs.present? %>
   # do something
<% else %>
   # do something else
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that since you have a potential for multiple categories, that you will want to do something with them, not just check if there are any.

In that case one thing you could do is render a partial for each category:

```
<%= render partial: my_category, collection: @category, as: :category %>
```

You should have a partial `_my_category.html.erb`:

```
<%= category %>
```

If there are no categories, no my_category partials will be rendered, so, no need for additional logic in the view.